# Output HTML with preg_replace_callback not in order

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I have the following HTML that's been returned from a function:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            <i>String that gets translated</i>
        </label>
        <textarea>
            <i>Another string</i>
        </textarea>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then I use `preg_replace_callback` to get the string between `<i>` tags and I replace it with a translated string, like below:

```
$translation = preg_replace_callback("/\<i\>(.+?)\<\/i\>/", 'translator', $html);

function translator($matches) {
    return __t($matches[1]);
}
```

However, when I output the html - `echo $translation;` - I get the following:

```
String that gets translated Another string<--this is not inside <i> tags
<fieldset>
    <legend>Title</legend>
    <div>
        <label>
            <i></i> <--the string should be placed here
        </label>
        <textarea>
            <i></i> <--and here
        </textarea>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This issue has been puzzling my head all day and I can't figure out a way to sort it out. How can I output the html and the translated string in the right order? Do I have to use `DOMDocument::loadHTML`, and if so how?

Comment: no issue with your code: https://3v4l.org/4PhnA did you tried to `echo __t($matches[1]);`

Comment: @Akam I can't `echo` the `__t($matches[1])` alone. They have to be echoed with the rest of the html. Why is this happening though? I think it's because `__t()` function echoes the string and not returning it. How can I prevent this? I can't edit the `__t()` function though.

Comment: @Akam check the sample code with the `t()` function echoing and not returning the string: https://3v4l.org/HoprL

Comment: If your `__t ` function not returning then its the problem..

Comment: You could use the `ob_XXX` functions to capture the output buffer into a string.

Comment: Instead of using `preg_replace_callback()`, use a DOM parser library. Then you can loop over the elements, echoing the parts that need to be output normally, and calling `__t()` on the parts that need to be translated.

Comment: @Barmar you are a life saver sir! The `ob_` function saved my day. Please use it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the output buffering functions.

```
ob_flush(); // flush any pending output buffer
ob_start();
$translation = preg_replace_callback("/\<i\>(.+?)\<\/i\>/", 'translator', $html);
ob_end_clean();

function translator($matches) {
    __t($matches[1]);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```